# Does Vue support svg elements?

Tags: vue.js, svg

I want to generate svg compoenents which uses svg tags. Does Vue supports that?

Note, that svg elements needs to be created in the corretc namespace and vue might not be able to handle that out of the box

Comment: vue can handle any html tags/attributes. Have you tried to use it?

Comment: Svg is not HTML hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Vue to create dynamic SVGs. There even is an example in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/editable-svg-icons.html#Animatable-Icons). In [this podcast](https://egghead.io/podcasts/sarah-drasner-talks-about-svg-animation-with-greensock-and-vue-js), Sarah Drasner talks about the combination of Vue, SVG and https://greensock.com/.

I have used this approach to build https://fn.hofmann-vratny.de/configurator, which simply binds SVG elements/properties to reactive Vue data. This worked really well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and add the SVG tags inside like:

```
<template> SVG Content Here </template>
```

**Note:** You might find some issues with certain SVG tags.

There's also some libraries you can use like [svg-to-vue-component](https://github.com/egoist/svg-to-vue-component)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "some" tags which create issues

Comment: I had issues with certain SVG's that had some lines that weren't being recognized so the SVG was not being rendered. But i only had this case once or twice.